# How to process pygame.get_pressed() to receive input

Tags: python, input, pygame

pygame.get_keypressed() returns a long list of 0s and 1s for each keys pressed that can be mapped by pygame. Sample below, is there a straight forward way to extract the letter representation of the key pressed?

I'm trying to avoid a long multiple if statements to test if `K_a`, `K_b`... ect is clicked, is there a way to process the 1s and 0s below?

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like number in binary representation so you could convert it into integer and use bitwise 'AND' to compare it with some 'mask' (which represents keys you need). I do not know if it is worth doing.

---

For testing more keys (for example h,e,l,o ) you can use

```
pressed = pygame.get_keypressed()

if all( (pressed[x] for x in (K_h, K_e, K_l, K_o)) ):
    print "all keys are pressed: h, e, l, o"

if any( (pressed[x] for x in (K_h, K_e, K_l, K_o)) ):
    print "at least one key is pressed: h, e, l, o"
```

You can turn it into function

```
def test_all_keys( list_of_keys, pressed ):
    return all( (pressed[x] for x in list_of_keys) )

if test_all_keys((K_h, K_e, K_l, K_o), pressed):
    print "all keys are pressed: h, e, l, o"
```

if you need list of pressed keys:

```
list_of_pressed = [ i for i in range(len(pressed)) if pressed[i] ]

if K_a in list_of_pressed:
    print "key 'a' was pressed"
```